# ASP.NET | How can I change .aspx extension to .html?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have tried URL-Routing method by using Global.asax file. But an error occurs like in the pictures. Please help me!!

[Global Asax File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Tcb.png)

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTI19.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, it's not searchable and we can't copy it into answers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS Manager > Click Handler Mappings > Add the same managed handlers that aspx has for html.

That's my best guess. It will work if SimpleHandleFactory was written extension agnostic. It will fail if it was not. I've never tried it myself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to rewrite `/index.html` into `index.aspx`. You just need to add this rewrite rule to your web.config:

```
<rule name="Rewrite index.html" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^index.html" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.aspx"/>
</rule>
```

Then if you will access `http://yourwebserver/index.html` web server will execute `/index.aspx`